# Can I use JOIN to get two usernames for say, createdbyUserID, and assignedtoUserID in a single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I’m stumped on how to display a recordset via a mysql query that will show two different "real" usernames in a history table that has columns for multiple userIDs (ie createdbyUserID, and assignedtoUserID) – I can get one of them via a JOIN, but how do I JOIN etc to show both since they will likely be different username?  Some other trick?  Is it via sql or some other function/loop?

Currently:

```
SELECT nxt_act_dev_hist.Created, nxt_act_dev_hist.assignedtoUserID,
       nxt_act_dev_hist.createdbyUserID, nxt_user.username  
FROM nxt_act_dev_hist 
JOIN nxt_user 
ON nxt_act_dev_hist.createdbyUserID=nxt_user.UserID
```

I'm a newbie here if you can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the same table twice, like this:

```
select
   -- some other fields
   createdByUser.UserName as CreatedByUserName,
   assignedtoUser.UserName as AssignedToUserName
from
    nxt_act_dev_hist
      JOIN nxt_user as createdByUser 
         ON nxt_act_dev_hist.createdbyUserID = createdByUser.UserID
      JOIN nxt_user as assignedtoUser
         ON nxt_act_dev_hist.createdbyUserID = assignedtoUser.UserID
```

I'm not a mysql guy, but that should work.

Comment: This was great and got me on the right track!  However, the mysql syntax requires that the join AS follows: JOIN nxt_user AS createdByUser ON nxt_act_dev_hist.CreateUserID = createdByUser.UserID - since mysql wouldn't recognize the nxt_user original table after including the AS createdByUser etc.  Very awesome help.